# Trend using deep learning possible with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow, deep-learning, project

As part of my final year project I want to create an app, thats main feature consists of notifying the user once the trend line (using deep learning, like TensorFlow) reaches a certain limit. For example, using stocks, if the user wanted to be notified when to buy Apple stocks, once the trend identified above a certain threshold, say above £350, then it will alert the user. Is this possible? What would I need to make this possible?

Comment: Have you looked at [Swift for Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/swift) yet?

Comment: Yes I have. Unfortunately they do not have forecasting yet. Any other suggestions?